# PHP Polymorphic Root Requires

Tags: php, directory, root

I have a directory/file tree as follows:

```
index.php

/frame/main_class.php
/frame/func/function_1.php
/frame/func/function_1.php
/cfg/config.php
```

---

```
//index.php

require('frame/main_class.php');
new main_class;
```

---

```
//frame/main_class.php

class main_class{
    public function __construct(){
        require('func/function_1.php');
        require('func/function_2.php');
        require('cfg/config.php');
    }
}
```

---

The weird part is that it works.  Maybe it is late and I am having a dumb-moment, but shouldn't "require('cfg/config');" be written "require('../cfg/config.php');"    ?

And if it is using the root of index.php, then "require('func/function_1.php');" shouldn't work, right?

I have quadruple checked the remote server thinking that maybe there was a stray file or two... there isn't.
How can the two require statements have a different base path.....?

Does anyone know of a code snippet that could cause this to happen?  I am working with some $_SERVER variables but I don't appear to be changing any of them....!?

---

["Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing."](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) Explicitly saying `include dirname(__FILE__) . '/path/to/file.php';`avoids this confusion. – DCoder

[Link to PHP Manual on "dirname".](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)

Comment: ["*Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the `include_path` specified. If the file isn't found in the `include_path`, include will finally check in the **calling script's own directory** and the **current working directory** before failing.*"](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) Explicitly saying `include dirname(__FILE__) . '/path/to/file.php';` avoids this confusion.

Comment: Ah, that makes complete and perfect sense.  So it checks the include_path and doesn't find it so it checks the scripts path and finds the functions.  For the cfg file it likely finds it from the include_path set in the ini.

Comment: The 'weird' bit for me is that this line works in the index.php file: `require('main_class.php');` How does that work when it's in a folder called frame?

Comment: @SamanthaP Sorry, but your design scares me!

Comment: @GordonM Lol, I know I know....... I have some serious self-taught design issues... you should see the complete code of my recent project.  You wouldn't sleep well tonight.  Classes inside of classes/conditional requires, PUBLIC as default, etc. etc.  I am trying to learn, obviously the hard way :)

Comment: @GordonM  Oh yeah, I forgot to mention parsing xml and html with regex (Please don't smite me), unsanitized $_GET and $_SERVER variables, curl requests to my own server that trigger other curl requests.... the list goes on....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP engine will look for the requested files in the current directory, but it will also look for them in the list of paths defined in INCLUDE_PATH.  If the include path lists the path from where your script is running then the given code will work.  If not then it wont.

For that reason amongst others it's not a good idea to rely on the include path to resolve the path of included files.  You should give the full path instead.

Comment: Can I ask a dim question?  The full path from where?

Comment: From the root.  You can get that fairly easily with the __DIR__ and the __FILE__ magic constants